# How to Export Data with custom button in Data Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am new in in Jquery, I am creating a custom button to export data from db in csv format of only selected rows, problem is that I dont know how to get the ID of the data, so that on based of selected IDs, I can make ajax call to PHP script to export selected records. How can I do that?

My Data table screenshot is,
[image]

Code is,

```
    $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({

        pageLength: 25,
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "stateSave": true,
        responsive: true,
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            'selectAll',
            'selectNone',
            {
                text: 'Export Selected Rows',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {

                    console.log(dt.row());

                }, exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        select: true,

    });
```

For the moment result of my code is,
[image]

Comment: My suggestion is that never show id from database to table.instead use increment operator.

Comment: Then how to recognize the rows?

Comment: by using `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `id` is the text of the fisrt cell of each row, on button click, search for the selected row by class (if you use the DataTables `select` plugin, the selected row will have the `selected` class):

```
function onButtonClick() {
   var id = $('#myTable')                 
              .find('tbody')
              .find('tr.selected')
              .find('td')
              .eq(0) // Get first cell
              .text() // Get the text of cell
              .trim(); // Trim the text

   // Call your method providing the id
}
```

---

I would recommend to initialize the DataTable plugin providing data like this:

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Your data
var data = [
   { ID: 0, ... },
   { ID: 1, ... },
   { ID: 2, ... },
   ....
];

// Initialize the plugin
$('#myTable').DataTable({
   dom: '...',
   data: data,
   columns: [
     {
       data: 'ID',
       title: 'ID'
     },
     ...
   ],
   buttons: [...]
});
```

Then, on button click you can retrieve the selected row's data like this:

```
var rowData = $('#myTable').DataTable().rows('.selected').data();
```

The `rowData` is an array-like object containing the data of the selected rows

You can check the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, but how to access that array?

Comment: Once you get the rowData object, just get the id, eg for the first row: rowData[0].ID

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below alternative inside your export button click. It gets all ids of selected tr (which has `selected` class) using jquery each function.

```
var data = {
  'selected_ids': []
};

$('tbody tr.selected').each(function() {
  data['selected_ids'][data['selected_ids'].length] = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
});
console.log(data); // var data holds the selected ids. You can pass it in your ajax data as it is.
```